# Laravel project pages not showing

Tags: laravel, mamp

I have cloned a laravel project from github and when I try to use it on my localhost, all I see is the homepage, which is fully functional, but has bits of content and images missing. Then if I try to go to any other route I get an error saying The requested URL  was not found on this server.

For reference I am using MAMP as the web server, I have checked the httpd file and everything seems okay, anyone got a clue what's going on?

Comment: show the npm error trace

Comment: Check your .env file, have you done any migrations that may be needed etc?
If you can provide more information that would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands in order :

```
cp .env.example .env
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
npm install 
npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

Comment: and did you set up  your env file and php artisan optimize:clear?

Comment: Yeah ran composer install but npm threw access errors, how do I fix this?

Comment: ran those and now the whole webpage is getting this error::SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: changed the .env and still getting the issues of not using the other links

Comment: `error::SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost`
this means that your DB user is not correctly set, are you sure everything is fine?

Comment: Yeah just changed the .env file as it changed the values back to default and still having the issue of routes not being on the server aparently?

Comment: Can i see your downloaded project in github. If you make correctly, you don't get any error and did you create database on mysql?